# TGALoader is loading image mirrored in vertical axis

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, tga

Loading a .obj model with a .mtl material using a Targa image as texture, the image is loaded mirrored. 
It can be noticed in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVqxh.png) where the left one is .tga and the right one is .png.

Opening both images in an image editor, they show to be the same. And, as long the .png image is loaded correctly, the problem is in the loader I'm using for .tga.

I'm using the [TGALoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TGALoader) class to load the texture. The problem seems to be related to the following code from function getTgaRGBA from TGALoader.js:

```
TGA_ORIGIN_MASK = 0x30,
TGA_ORIGIN_SHIFT = 0x04,
TGA_ORIGIN_BL = 0x00,
TGA_ORIGIN_BR = 0x01,
TGA_ORIGIN_UL = 0x02,
TGA_ORIGIN_UR = 0x03;

function getTgaRGBA( width, height, image, palette ) {
    var x_start,
        y_start,
        x_step,
        y_step,
        x_end,
        y_end,
        data = new Uint8Array( width * height * 4 );
    //switch ( 0x02 ) {
    switch ( ( header.flags & TGA_ORIGIN_MASK ) >> TGA_ORIGIN_SHIFT  ) {
        default:
        case TGA_ORIGIN_UL:
            x_start = 0;
            x_step = 1;
            x_end = width;
            y_start = 0;
            y_step = 1;
            y_end = height;
            break;

        case TGA_ORIGIN_BL:
            x_start = 0;
            x_step = 1;
            x_end = width;
            y_start = height - 1;
            y_step = - 1;
            y_end = - 1;
            break;

        case TGA_ORIGIN_UR:
            x_start = width - 1;
            x_step = - 1;
            x_end = - 1;
            y_start = 0;
            y_step = 1;
            y_end = height;
            break;

        case TGA_ORIGIN_BR:
            x_start = width - 1;
            x_step = - 1;
            x_end = - 1;
            y_start = height - 1;
            y_step = - 1;
            y_end = - 1;
            break;

    }
```

If the result from switch was 0x02, the image would be loaded corrected, without being mirrored. I've tested with different .tga images, and all of them resulted the same mirroring.

I don't understand well what does the parameter of switch means... Could you guys help me to figure it out, and how could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texture is flipped. Use this pattern:

```
var loader = new THREE.TGALoader();

var texture = loader.load( 'myTexture.tga' );

texture.flipY = true;
```

three.js r.74

Comment: Yeah, but how come the .png version is loaded correctly, and .tga isn't? I think it's some issue within the TGALoader.  Is there a way that I can check automatically wether the image is flipped or not? So that I always correct it before I use?

Comment: Because the .tga file is treated as a `THREE.DataTexture`, which does not flip Y by default. Study the source code, or step through it with a debugger.

Comment: A bug as been fixed in `TGALoader` in r.76dev. Setting `flipY` should no longer be necessary.